# Enterprise Architect Schema Composer Root Class Cardinality

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am trying to create a custom script that generates a schema from the EA schema composer.
For this script I need to access the cardinality of specified root classes (you can set cardinalities for classes that you mark as root class in the composer).

I have looked through this specification: https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.1/automation/sc_schematypeclass.html

I have tried calling `IsRoot()` which returns True or False and calling `GetFacet("root")` which also returns True or False. Is there any way to get the values of the cardinality from a root class using automation in EA?

Comment: No idea about that new stuff, but for an element you need to `SELECT cardinality FROM t_object WHERE object_id = ...`

Comment: Thanks qwerty. It seems that the Schema Composer files are stored as documents. I now used a query as you suggested to get the StrContent of the document, and can then parse the necessary information from the document (serialized in xml). I just hoped that I overlooked the method for cardinalities since all the other schema composer information is exposed by the object model.

Comment: Looks like you got it. You can write a short self-answer. Should winter become cold I'll add that to Inside EA.